# Devise custom forgot password method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I made it possible for one to register and log in with a username (I did it in a dirty way, but for the user it is invisible) and I have the email in another model called `ContactInfo` which has a one-to-one relationship with `User`.

So I need to make my app use the email in `ContactInfo` instead of `User` when it's necessary to send an email (as in this case it is to recover the password), how can I do that?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note: This response has been heavily edited based on the clarification received from the original poster below.**

If you really must do it this way, see here: [Send Password Reset to a Different Email - Devise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48287534/send-password-reset-to-a-different-email-devise)

Although I feel the need to reiterate that this is not recommended. Why use Devise if you're just going to change its internals? You've already lost more time than you're going to gain by doing this, and you're opening yourself up to bugs and inconsistent behavior throughout your application.

If it's not too late: Devise has a wiki for how to [use a username instead of an email](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)  which does not require a new table or hacking the internals. If you do that, then sending a reset email via username is as easy as [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address#allow-users-to-recover-their-password-or-confirm-their-account-using-their-username)

Comment: > "Does that help or are you asking how to overwrite the Devise lookup for an email?"

I'm asking how to overwrite the Devise controller to use the email I have in `ContactInfo` instead of `User`, I already made the associations and stuff.

Comment: @OiciTrap see the updated comment for two options moving forward.